# Function template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to create a function template with a default implementation and some specializations as follows:

```
template <typename T>
inline T fromBool(bool var) { return var ? T(1) : T(0); }

template <>
inline Vec2 fromBool<Vec2>(bool var) { return var ? Vec2(1, 1) : Vec2(0, 0); }

// Some more specializations for Vec3, etc
```

This is an example definition of the complex type `Vec2`:

```
struct Vec2 {
  double x, y;
  Vec2(double a, double b) { x = a; y = b; }
}
```

However, the specialization is not working. When I call `fromBool<const Vec2>(var)`, the compiler uses the default implementation (the one for simple types).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works as far as I can tell http://ideone.com/LIRxTQ

Comment: @StoryTeller Found out the problem was I need to define this for `const` types. Is there a workaround on redefining all specializations for `const`?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual problem?

Comment: @manatttta More code please!

Comment: In general, it works, so much is sure. What you're doing wrong is hard to tell, because you have neither provided the required minimal example nor have you provide the problems it causes. Remember, "is not working" is your interpretation and that is only of secondary important. First, you have to provide the facts (what you did, what you saw, what you expected)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment, it seems like you want a version which should work with both `Vec2` and `const Vec2`

```
template <typename T>
struct fromBool_impl {
    static T fromBool(bool var) { return var ? T(1) : T(0); }
};
template <>
struct fromBool_impl<Vec2> {
    static Vec2 fromBool(bool var) {
        return var ? Vec2(1, 1) : Vec2(0, 0);
    }
};

template <typename T>
inline T fromBool(bool var) {
    return fromBool_impl<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::fromBool(var);
}

int main() {
    fromBool<Vec2>(true);
    fromBool<const Vec2>(true);
}
```

---

Note: if `T` is reference type, the behavior is undefined.

---

The above code use `std::remove_cv` from C++11, it's not hard to implement it in C++98, you can find one possible implementation from [`std::remove_cv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv)